# Google Webmater Tools under the Blocked URLs page (robots.txt)

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

In the Blocked URLs page there is a text box called *Edit to Test Changes* where one can edit the robots.txt content for testing.

Before the robots.txt file was edited this text box was showing it's content. I modified the robots.txt file and the text box was not showing it's content anymore. After such a change I reverted back it's contents to as it was previously, but the text box still remained empty. Two weeks have passed and still no changes.

Can anyone guide me on how I can start see again my robots.txt in the *Edit to Test Changes* text box in the Google Webmaster Tools.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

in **Webmaster Tools** go to **Crawl** -> **Fetch as Google**, click red button saying "**Fetch**"

robots.txt status under **Blocked URLs** should update within couple of days

let me know if that helps